# SQL para agrupar registros

Tags: sql, sql-server

Fiz a consulta abaixo para carregar os registros com maior data de saída (um mesmo registro pode ter várias datas):

```
SELECT   RA, MAX(Data_Out) AS Data_Saida, Placa
FROM     dbo.RA_Vehicles
GROUP BY RA, Placa
ORDER BY RA
```

Estou tendo dificuldades quando incluo a coluna `placa` (carrega todos os registros). Resumindo, preciso de uma consulta que carregue os contratos e respectivas placas com a maior data de saída (o contrato 30 por exemplo, pode ter dois registros, um com a placa A e data X e outro com a placa B com data Y. Preciso carregar somente o registro com maior data).

Teria que utilizar uma subconsulta?

Comment: está usando sql server? mySQL?

Comment: Estou usando SQL server

Comment: acho que o mais de boas é fazer com subconsulta msm.. tipo essa resposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/44064826/4551469

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como comentado, acredito que o ideal na solução seja mesmo com subconsulta, semelhante a [esta outra resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44064826/4551469) do *SO*.

```
//inner join
SELECT v1.RA, v1.Placa, v1.Data_Out AS Data_Saida
FROM dbo.RA_Vehicles v1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT RA, MAX(Data_Out) Data_Out AS Data_Saida
    FROM dbo.RA_Vehicles
    GROUP BY RA
) v2
ON v1.RA = v2.RA AND v1.Data_Out = v2.Data_Out
```

---

Existem outras formas de fazer a comparação, e se houver preocupação com performance você pode analisar possíveis soluções, como sugerido [nesse link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6659/sql-exists-vs-in-vs-join-performance-comparison/).

Comment: Deu certinho amigo... Muito obrigado... Me ajudou muito!!!

Comment: massa, @Saulo!! =) lembra de marcar a resposta como aceita ;) e qq coisa, manda mais pergunta pra cima..

Comment: pode deixar... Valeu